# Measure to calculate difference in averages between currently selected cycle and previous cycle

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have a table called 'Table', which contains two numerical columns, one called 'Value' and one called 'CycleID'. CycleID is a number with the largest being the most recent cycle.

I want a measure that allows a user to select a CycleID and calculate the following:
[Current Cycle Average] - [Previous Cycle Average]

This is in Power Pivot and cannot rely on useful functions like SELECTEDVALUE. So I tried the following.

Set up measure for average value

```
Av Value:=AVERAGE( Table[Value] )
```

the above should simply return average value when user selects using a slicer a specific report cycle, all good.

Then I define a measure to find the previous cycle ID based on current selection:

```
Previous Cycle:=CALCULATE( MAXA( Table[CycleID] ), FILTER( ALL(Table), Table[CycleID] < MAXA( Table[CycleID] ) ) )
```

which works fine, i.e. user selects cycle id 120, previous cycle returns the next largest cycle id.

Then I try work out average value for the previous cycle (PC):

```
Av Value PC:=CALCULATE( [Av Value], FILTER( Table, Table[CycleID] = [Previous Cycle] ) )
```

The above however returns BLANK. FILTER should just return the table with only the rows corresponding to the Previous Cycle ID and then give me the average. Why is it returning BLANK?

Comment: IIUC, you want to subtract two rolling averages? Btw, the black might have to do with using measures with a filter inside calculate

Comment: To summarise I wish to subtract average for cycle x from average for cycle y where y > x.